# Getting "cumulusci.core.exceptions.OrgNotFound: Org named Dev was not found in keychain" for cci org default Dev

Tags: salesforcedx, scratch-org, cumulusci

I am trying to run my robot test on circleci, I am getting below error when I run cci org default Dev command:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "venv/bin/cci", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('cumulusci', 'console_scripts', 'cci')()
  File "/home/circleci/repo/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 764, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/circleci/repo/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 717, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/home/circleci/repo/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1137, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/home/circleci/repo/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1137, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/home/circleci/repo/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 956, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/home/circleci/repo/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 555, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/circleci/repo/cumulusci/cli/cci.py", line 209, in new_func
    func(config, *args, **kw)
  File "/home/circleci/repo/cumulusci/cli/cci.py", line 841, in org_default
    config.keychain.set_default_org(org_name)
  File "/home/circleci/repo/cumulusci/core/keychain/BaseProjectKeychain.py", line 162, in set_default_org
    org = self.get_org(name)
  File "/home/circleci/repo/cumulusci/core/keychain/BaseProjectKeychain.py", line 185, in get_org
    self._raise_org_not_found(name)
  File "/home/circleci/repo/cumulusci/core/keychain/BaseProjectKeychain.py", line 194, in _raise_org_not_found
    raise OrgNotFound(f"Org named {name} was not found in keychain")
cumulusci.core.exceptions.OrgNotFound: Org named Dev was not found in keychain

Exited with code exit status 1
```

Which folder it is trying to check the Org or any config missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CumulusCI's out-of-the-box org definition is called `dev` (rather than `Dev`), and org names are case-sensitive. Use `cci org default dev` instead.

Note, additionally, that setting a default org is not required in CumulusCI. You can always specify the org target for a specific task or flow command with `--org dev`.

Comment: This works fine now, Thank you